# How to resize the bottom mini window?

Tags: spacemacs, window

[image]

What I did was

1. I installed the fresh spacemacs
2. I added org and osx layer
3. I used the doom-1337 theme
4. `C-c a` to select agenda commands

Then, the bottom letters are barely seen as the mode-line height is a little bit higher than normal.

I think if I can adjust the height of the bottom mini-window, it will show them properly, but it does not allow me to adjust the size with mouse drag.

I think there must be a way to adjust the window size, but I don't know how.

Can anyone help how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this were about the size of the minibuffer/echo-area window then this might be the answer: `M-x customize-option resize-mini-windows`.

`C-h v resize-mini-windows` tells us:

> **`resize-mini-windows`** is a variable defined in `C source code`.
>
> Its value is `grow-only`
>
> Documentation:
>
> How to resize mini-windows (the minibuffer and the echo area).
>
> - A value of `nil` means don't automatically resize mini-windows.
> - A value of `t` means resize them to fit the text displayed in them.
> - A value of `grow-only`, the default, means let mini-windows grow only;
>   they return to their normal size when the minibuffer is closed, or the
>   echo area becomes empty.
>
> You can customize this variable.
>
> This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
> version 25.1 of Emacs.

---

However, it looks like the buffer you're worried about making larger is *not* the minibuffer/echo-area window.  It looks like it's for buffer `*Agenda Commands*`, and you seem to have a (somewhat tall) tab bar in the place of its mode-line (?).

I'm assuming you don't see the problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file).  In that case, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

If you find out that a part of your init file causes the problem, if that part comes from using some library, you might want to file a bug report with its maintainer.  Or you might need to revisit some customization you're doing, if that's causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, you're right. It does not happen when ```emacs -Q``` The culprit would be from the ```doom-theme``` I'm too lazy to file a bug report them, but later I will do that. For a while, the workaround is to increase the window-min-height like ```(setq window-min-height 15)``` So, I can live like that for a while, but I may talk to the doom theme writer later. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. You might want to accept or upvote the answer, if you think it might help others -- unless you feel the question is still open, and you want to perhaps get a better answer. (You can nevertheless change your mind any time about which answers are more helpful.)